# I'm having a problem with python in relation to tuples

Tags: python

I am trying to create a game (tic tac toe) and I have to create a board (called `tab`) using 3 tuples that each has 3 elements that represent a position on a line. A "X" is represented by the number 1, a "O" by -1 and an empty space by 0. I am trying to create a function that receives an argument (in this case the board is the argument) and says if it represents a valid board or not, however it always gives me the wrong answer (in this case says it's false) and I don't know why.

```
tab = ((1, -1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, -1, 1))

def eh_tabuleiro(tab):
    if len(tab) == 3:
        if len(tab[0]) == 3 and len(tab[1]) == 3 and len(tab[2]) == 3:
            if tab[0][0] or tab[0][1] or tab[0][2] or tab[1][0] or tab[1][1] or tab[1][2] or tab[2][0] or tab[2][1] or tab[2][2] != 1 or -1 or 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True           
            
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

For a board to be valid it needs to be a tuple with three tuples and 3 elements inside each smaller tuple. If it has 2 elements or instead of 1/-1/0 has a "-1" or any other thing the function returns False. As you can see my board is correct and it says it is not. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're almost there. The `or` expression is wrong. Do 2 for loops, one for the rows, other nested for the columns, and check if the current position is different from 1, -1 or 0.

Comment: That big `if` doesn't evaluate as you want it to. A more Pythonic way to express that condition is: `if not all(tab[i][j] in (1, -1, 0) for i in range(3) for j in range(3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the long chain of `or` statements. Compare the following:

```py
if 1 or 2 == 3:  # Python reads this as `if 1 or (2 == 3):`
    print('oops')

# prints 'oops'
```

```py
if (1 == 3) or (2 == 3):
    print('oops')

# does not print
```

---

Suggestion for a more readable implementation:

```py
def is_valid(tab):
    if not isinstance(tab, tuple):
        return False

    if len(tab) != 3:
        return False

    for row in tab:
        if not isinstance(row, tuple):
            return False

        if len(row) != 3:
            return False
        
        for element in row:
             if element not in (-1, 0, 1):
                 return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to invent a new syntax. It does not matter that you (or I) can guess what is expected, what matter is what Python understand.

This line:

```
if tab[0][0] or tab[0][1] or tab[0][2] or tab[1][0] or tab[1][1] or tab[1][2] or tab[2][0] or tab[2][1] or tab[2][2] != 1 or -1 or 0:
```

will return True as soon as one of the elements between `or` is `True`, and the integer values 1 or -1 give True in a boolean context.

What you want is to know whether the set produced by all values is a subset of (0, 1, -1). Just test that instead:

```
...
if (set(tab[0]) | set(tab[1]) | set(tab[2])).issubset({1, 0, -1}):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: `issubset({1, 2, 3})` ?

Comment: @Niloct: Oops I should have had a coffee before writing that! Thank you for your comment...

Comment: No problem. By the way, your answer would analyse the whole board right ? The accepted answer would stop in the first cell with problems.